# dynamically added anchor click doesn't call function in jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, click, anchor

My page fetches string data from local SQL and appends it to data-role='listview' as li using function below(simplified version)

```
function CreateListview{
   var temp ='<li><a href="#" class="anchor">String Here</a></li>';
   $("#<ul>-selector").append(temp).listview("refresh");
}
```

well, it works fine so I binded a click event for the anchor(class='.anchor')

```
$(document).on('vclick', '.anchor', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#ul-selector > a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});
```

OR

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#ul-selector > li a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});
```

OR even

```
$(document).on('vclick', 'a', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});
```

**But nothing works**
I double-checked if click event on other elements works by using the function below on dynamically added li and it sometimes works and sometime doesn't.

I don't know why it works randomly,

but I checked that click events are fired on some other dynamically added elements.

```
$(document).on('vclick', '#ul-selector > li', function(e){
  alert("<li> CLICKED");
});
```

When it comes to binding click function to dynamically added **anchors**, the function won't be fired..
could it be a bug? or am I writing codes wrong?

Can you give me a working example binding click event to dynamically added anchor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

**Problem**: with cordova, 'click' on anchor doesn't fire function even with e.preventDefault(); Rather, 'touchstart' works fine.

**Solution**: 'click' -> 'touchstart' to work on devices

```
$(document).on('touchstart', '#anchor-selector', function(){
   alert("touch");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems works fine for me.

```js
function CreateListView() {
   var temp ='<li><a href="#" class="anchor">String Here</a></li>';
   $("#selector").append(temp).listview("refresh");
}

$(document).on('vclick', '.anchor', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});

$("#createLi").on("vclick", function(){
    CreateListView();
    alert("test");
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js"></script>

<div id="content">
    <ul id="selector">
    </ul>
</div>
<input id="createLi" type="button" value="create li"/>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: does this work in cordova as well..? I am finding that only anchors is not calling a click function.. everything else works fine with click

Answer (score 0):

bind the event after you append the html like this

```
function CreateListview{
   var temp ='<li><a href="#" class="anchor">String Here</a></li>';
   $("#<ul>-selector").append(temp).listview("refresh");

$("#<ul>-selector > li").on("click",function(){
 alert("<li> CLICKED");
});

}
```

check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/alenjoy333/yecyezwv/) you can apply the same logic here

Comment: hm.. only works on the first click, then i have to refresh the page to make it work again but still, works only on the first click. It shows that anchor click works, but not from the second click.

Answer (score 0):

You're not listening to the `click` event but `vclick`(???).

```
$("yourUl").on('click', '.anchor', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  alert("ANCHOR CLICKED");
});
```

Comment: it's for jquery mobile, i guess? even if i used 'click' it still doesn't work

Comment: @Joon.P, Ah ok. I've just checked it out. But it says that it's better to use `click` rather than `vclick` because of a latency on webkit browser.

`$(document).on('click', '.anchor', function(e){ .... });`